# after federated authentication, redirect to originally requested url

Tags: adfs, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

We've setup federated security using ThinkTecture server.

When a user wishes to access a particular URL, they get redirected to the Identity Provider Server (IDP), they login, get authenticated.

Then, the IDP server will redirect the user back to the "Redirect URL" specified in the configuration for that Relying Party.

Instead, I want it to be redirected to the originally requested URL.

Is this possible? I've read a little about the wreply parameter, but not sure how I use this and intercept the authentication levels calls on the original web server, before the redirect.

**Update**
I've realised that my problem is due to my url containing a hash, e.g. **http://domain.com/#customer/123** and nothing after the hash is passed into the redirect url within WIF. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to your app to remember context info like this in the wctx param. If you're using WIF in the RP then this should be done automatically.

Comment: My wctx param is automatically populated with this: &wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252f. So, if I populate this wctx with some guid or the original url to identify the original request, how do I identify it after the authenticated redirect back to the ReplyTo/'Redirect Url'. Or is it simply based on the username? Sounds like the wreply param is useless.

Comment: This answer provides a more detailed overview of your answer (I think). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324627/url-redirection-from-adfs-server

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was happening. I am using WIF and as Brock's answer suggested it should be doing everything itself...and it was.

Normally if you request a url like: **http://example.com/page** and the 'Redirect To'/ReplyTo setting in ThinkTecture is just **http://example.com/**.

Then when WIF calls out to the STS, it takes the path of the requested domain, in this case **/path** and adds it to the **&ru** param within the **&wctx** param. The **&wctx** param will look like this: **rm=0&id=passive&ru=%2fpage**.

Then after the STS has authenticated it redirects the user back to the ReplyTo url, **http://example.com** with a body parameter of **wctx** and WIF picks this up and uses the **ru** param to do another redirect.

The **problem** is that my requested url was **http://example.com/#page** and WIF doesn't include the **#page** in the **ru** param. So my **ru** param was just **/**, so it kept redirecting to **http://example.com** which there was correct (yet incorrect).

Guess I need to set the ru value myself with the full URL... unless there is a better way.

Comment: have you figured out a way to set the ru value programatically?

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue too. Did you ever figure out an answer?